# How to tell the gcc linker to add a .reloc section?

Tags: c, gcc, portable-executable

I want my C executable to contain the base relocation table.
but the linker doesn't add it.

is there a way I can tell it to add the base relocation table?

Comment: wild guess: -fPIE ?

Comment: @user253751 doesn't work

Comment: @AngryJohn: did you find any way to do this?  We also need the GCC linker to emit a `.reloc` section, for a bare-metal target, in order that we can fully handle position independent code, but so far GCC have said "you need to link with `-pie` if you want a PIE executable. BUT that does not work with `-elf`/`-eabi` targets as there is no loader.  Since there is no loader and shared libraries are not supported with bare metal, you need to have a modified binutils to do the right thing and have a correct target".  Sounds like the GCC linker can't do it without modification...?